# Why are there multiple spirals in the Weyl-type sum?

Tags: exponential-sum

This question comes from the Mathematica documentation.
In the documentation of $e$ [1](https://wolfram.com/xid/0p2l-lukcqs), it shows a neat example of Weyl-type sum:

Letting
$$ f(n;r,p) \triangleq \sum_{k=1}^{n} e^{i~r~k^p},
$$
then the sequence ${\left\{f(n;1000e,\frac{1}{2})\right\}}_{n=1}^{2000}$ shows like [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsvKK.png), which contains multiple spirals.

When various $r$ is adopted, the figures become different. Another example is the case for $r=10000\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant.
The result of such a case can be seen in the Neat Example part of [3](https://wolfram.com/xid/0eny5hueq-hpl3se).
Moreover, modification on $p$ has different effects, which can be seen in [4](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Exp/visualizations/19/).

However, there are no references in these Mathematica documentations, and I can't find relevant explanation via searching.

A basic explanation of this problem is separating the real and the imaginary parts. Letting $$ g(n;r,p) \triangleq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \cos(r~k^p), h(n;r,p) \triangleq \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sin(r~k^p),
$$
we can find multiple plateaus in the figure.
For instance, ${\left\{g(n;1000e,\frac{1}{2})\right\}}_{n=1}^{2000}$ has the figure [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrsyW.png).
The aligned plateaus of $g$ and $h$ create the spirals in $f$.
However, such an explanation does not make much help.
I still wonder why these plateaus happen, why the plateaus of $g$ and $h$ are aligned, and what's the relationship between the plateaus   and the value of $r$ and $p$.

- This question is partly like that in [6](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3740360/a-curious-property-of-exponential-sums-for-rational-polynomials). However, since $k^p$ is not a polynomial, the graph does not have periodicity, and other method should be adopted.